# ::ng-deep changes other components style

Tags: css, components, markdown, border

I am using a .md file to display information in a dialog from Material for Angular.
The thing is that tables in markdown files, when they are displayed in the DOM, there are no borders. So I tried to add some css.

```
::ng-deep table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
  border:2px solid black;
}

::ng-deep th {
  border:2px solid black;
}

::ng-deep td {
  border:1px solid black;
}
```

If don't add `::ng-deep`, no style is applied on my table, so I am forced to use it. It works fine, my table now has borders but it affects my other components, how to fix that ?

EDIT : this is my template :

`<div markdown [src]="data"></div>`

Comment: set unique `class` to those DOM you want too apply css on... and use `.yourClass ::ng-deep...`

Comment: weird result : border is not at all applied on my table, but on the div which is the container of my markdown content.

Comment: thats because my template is : <div markdown [src]="data" class="tdborder thborder tableborder"></div>

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Answer is add parent class to dialog and use `::ng-deep` to apply styles for that component only

You can add class to dialog as shown below

```
const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(DialogOverviewExampleDialog, {
      width: '250px',
      data: {name: this.name, animal: this.animal},
      panelClass: 'my-parent-class'
});
```

and add styles as

```
.my-parent-class ::ng-deep table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
  border:2px solid black;
}

.my-parent-class ::ng-deep th {
  border:2px solid black;
}

.my-parent-class ::ng-deep td {
  border:1px solid black;
}
```

**Explanation**: Material dialog is a dynamic component

**Static component HTML**

```
<table _ngcontent-c0>...</table>
```

**Static component CSS**

```
table[_ngcontent-c0] { ... }
```

**Dynamic component HTML**

```
<table>...</table>
```

**Dynamic component CSS**

```
table { ... }
```

Notice the difference for static component attribute `_ngcontent-c0` is added by angular, Angular use this Technic to create component specific styles (To apply styles for that particular component), but for dynamic component no attribute is being added. **This is the reason your static component styles not applied to dynamic component**

To make this work we used `::ng-deep` before any class to remove that attribute `_ngcontent-c0` and select dynamic component, **so when `::ng-deep` is used your styles are no more component specific (it will be applied to all components).** This is the reason we use parent class to apply styles for that component only and dynamically created component too.

Answer (score 25):

I hope I have clearly understood your question.
If you are trying to affect the style of a child component without affecting all the other components, use :host before ::ng-deep.

```
:host ::ng-deep .my-class
```

This will only change the style in the component in which you change the style.