# Angular how to use ng-deep but still affect only one component?

Tags: angular, sass, ng-deep

In an Angular application, using Angular Material for themes, I'm trying to update a css class in a component when my theme changes to dark.

This would work, but it would affect all components, loosing the encapsulation:

```scss
::ng-deep .dark-theme { // must have ::ng-deep to see .dark-theme on body
  .action-button:hover {
    color: #ffffff;
  }
}
```

How can I have same result, but only for one component?

I've tried this as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62789521/11107672) but doesn't seems to work for me:

```scss
::ng-deep .dark-theme {
  :host .action-button:hover {
    color: #ffffff;
  }
}
// OR
:host ::ng-deep .dark-theme .action-button:hover {
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

Comment: What ‘doesn’t work’ In the last two cases? Styles don’t apply or styles leak?

Comment: classes are just not applied might have something to do with the fact that the `.dark-theme` is applied on the body, but I don't really know

Comment: check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69734259/5536695), if it helps in anyway

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

As we set the View Encapsulation(Emulated) to the required component the styles will be applied only to the elements within the component's template.

@Component({
selector: 'app-emulated-encapsulation',
template: '',
styles: '',
encapsulation:  View Encapsulation .Emulated,
})

With the limited info provided to actually test the scenario, you can avoid using ng-deep and host too if setting the Encapsulation property in @Component block fixes your issue.

Pls refer - https://angular.io/guide/view-encapsulation for further info.